# Business Hours Age field on page layout?

Tags: case, page-layout, fields

Salesforce provides the **Business Hours Age** Case's field which is available in reports, is that possible to add this same field to the Case page layout? Is there anyway to get this field by SOQL or something like that?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336686&type=1

Comment: the field is already enabled in the org and I'm able to add it in reports, my question is if there is anyway of getting this field and place it into Case's page layout

Comment: It's a report-only field as noted by the doc. Vote for this idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZCLUA3/case-object-durationage-in-business-hours